# Cannot locate Config/General.pm Perl module in @INC?

Tags: perl, cpan

I am running a perl script that uses Config::General. However, when I run the script, I get the error:

```
Can't locate Config/General.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config::General module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at test.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 6.
```

When I try to install it myself (using 'cpanm Config::General'), I get:

```
Can't write to /Library/Perl/5.18 and /usr/local/bin: Installing modules to /Users/../perl5
```

Not sure if I should attempt to try to install as root since this is a work computer? Any other options?

Comment: You can install modules into your own lib folder (e.g.: under your home directory). The `local::lib` module can be used to manage where things get installed and where Perl looks when `use`ing a module.  The [bootstrapping technique](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#The-bootstrapping-technique) section of the docs can get you started. Once you've followed those instructions to set up a lib dir and modify your environment to point to it, you'll be able to install modules with `cpanm` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use `cpanm`, you may try this approach:

1. Install all modules with prefix `~/perl5`

```
cpanm -L ~/perl5 Config::General
```

2. Set `@INC` to includ that when running your program, for example:

```
perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 test.pl
```

The path looks a bit odd, but that's because cpan distributions may contain something more than a `.pm` file.

Generally speaking this should work most of the time. :-)